# Increasing the distance between nodes from the 1cm default using "right=of" option

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code has `TikZ` drawing parallel line $\ell$ and $m$ and intersecting line $k$. I drew line $m$ by first positioning the origin, labeled O, on it, and using `\coordinate[left=of O](P);` and
`\coordinate[label={[fill=white]right:$m$},right=of O](Q);` to position two other points on $m$, and issuing the command `\draw[draw=blue!30,latex-latex] (P) -- (Q);` to draw the line. By default, this makes the line 2 centimeters long.  The display would look much better if I moved P further to the left and Q further to the right of O.  How do I enter that as an option?

Angles $z_{1}$ and $z_{3}$ are a bit too close to line $k$. How do I shift them horizontally?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate(O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[left=of O](P);
\coordinate[label={[fill=white]right:$m$},right=of O](Q);
\coordinate(A) at (110:2);
\coordinate[left=of A](R);
\coordinate[label={[fill=white]right:$\ell$},right=of A](S);

\draw[draw=blue!30,latex-latex] (P) -- (Q);
\draw[draw=blue!30,latex-latex] (R) -- (S);
\draw (O) -- (A);
\draw[-latex] (O) -- (-70:1) coordinate (C);
\draw[-latex] (A) -- +(110:1) coordinate[label={[fill=white]above left:$k$}] (B);

\node[above right] at (A) {$\scriptstyle{x}$};
\node[below left] at (A) {$\scriptstyle{y}$};
\node[above left] at (O) {$\scriptstyle{z_{1}}$};
\node[above right] at (O) {$\scriptstyle{z_{2}}$};
\node[below right] at (O) {$\scriptstyle{z_{3}}$};
\node[below left] at (O) {$\scriptstyle{z_{4}}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\node [above right=10cm and 20cm of A] {}`...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say

```
[right=<dimension> of <coordinate>]
```

rather than just using `[right] at (<coordinate>)`. For example,

```
\node [above left=12mm and 15mm of A] {P};
```

will create the node with a `P` in it 12mm above and 15mm to the left of `A`.

So, you might move `P` and `Q` something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate(O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[left=20mm of O](P);
    \coordinate[label={[fill=white]right:$m$},right=15mm of O](Q);
    \coordinate(A) at (110:2);
    \coordinate[left=of A](R);
    \coordinate[label={[fill=white]right:$\ell$},right=of A](S);

    \draw[draw=blue!30,latex-latex] (P) -- (Q);
    \draw[draw=blue!30,latex-latex] (R) -- (S);
    \draw (O) -- (A);
    \draw[-latex] (O) -- (-70:1) coordinate (C);
    \draw[-latex] (A) -- +(110:1) coordinate[label={[fill=white]above left:$k$}] (B);

    \node[above right] at (A) {$\scriptstyle{x}$};
    \node[below left] at (A) {$\scriptstyle{y}$};
    \node[above left] at (O) {$\scriptstyle{z_{1}}$};
    \node[above right] at (O) {$\scriptstyle{z_{2}}$};
    \node[below right] at (O) {$\scriptstyle{z_{3}}$};
    \node[below left] at (O) {$\scriptstyle{z_{4}}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: moving P and Q]

## EDIT

You might also consider using the `angles` library to make drawing the angles a bit easier. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,angles}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      every label/.append style={fill=white},
      my blue/.style={draw=blue!30}
    ]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \coordinate [left=20mm of O] (P);
    \coordinate [label={right:$m$}, right=15mm of O] (Q);
    \coordinate (A) at (110:2);
    \coordinate [left=of A] (R);
    \coordinate [label={right:$\ell$}, right=of A] (S);

    \draw [my blue, latex-latex] (P) -- (Q);
    \draw [my blue, latex-latex] (R) -- (S);
    \draw (O) -- (A);
    \draw [-latex] (O) -- (-70:1) coordinate (C);
    \draw [-latex] (A) -- +(110:1) coordinate [label={above left:$k$}] (B);

    \path pic ["$\scriptstyle{z_{1}}$", my blue, angle radius=5mm] {angle=A--O--P}
      pic ["$\scriptstyle{z_{2}}$", my blue, angle radius=5.5mm] {angle=Q--O--A}
      pic ["$\scriptstyle{z_{3}}$", my blue, angle radius=5mm] {angle=C--O--Q}
      pic ["$\scriptstyle{z_{4}}$", my blue, angle radius=5.5mm] {angle=P--O--C}
      pic ["$\scriptstyle{x}$", my blue, angle radius=5mm] {angle=S--A--B}
      pic ["$\scriptstyle{y}$", my blue, angle radius=5mm] {angle=R--A--O}
    ;

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: angles]

Then you can alter the `angle radius` and/or `angle eccentricity` to adjust the positioning of the marker. See page 519, section 39 (Angle library) for details.

## EDIT 2

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
\path
  (135:2.5mm) node [xshift=-1mm] {$\scriptstyle{z_{1}}$}
  (45:2.5mm) node {$\scriptstyle{z_{2}}$}
  (-45:2.5mm) node [xshift=1.5mm] {$\scriptstyle{z_{3}}$}
  (-135:2.5mm) node {$\scriptstyle{z_{4}}$}
  ;
```

[image: tweaked angles]

Comment: What is the default value for `above left`?  For the positioning of $z_{1}$, the height above point O is fine; I want it moved leftward 2mm.

Comment: @Adelyn I think the defaults are generally 10mm. But if you just want to move it left, you can add `xshift=-2mm`. However, I recommend looking at the `angles` library for marking angles. (See edit above. This doesn't move things much but it shows you how to do it. That is, I've probably moved the wrong angles but you can just switch the values - I picked randomly just so they were opposite.)

Comment: I originally had `\path pic[draw, angle radius=3mm,"$z_{1}$",angle eccentricity=1.75] {angle = A--O--P};` to mark the angel for $z_{1}$ and similar commands for the other angles about point O.  Having the arcs about point O is ugly.

Comment: @Adelyn You don't have to draw them. I did it that way mostly to show what was going on.

Comment: I used the option `xshift=-1mm` to move $z_{1}$ leftward and `xshift=1mm` to move $z_{3}$ rightward.  Thanks.  (I think that you are right that `above right` moves the node up 1 cm and to the right 1 cm.)

Comment: @Adelyn Great! I also added an example using this. (See above.)